# How to set last column header to a fixed size and maintain it

Tags: python, pyqt

A code below create `QTreeWidget` with 7 (actually 8) columns.

I want the last column #7 to be used as a spacer. So when a dialog is resized there is always a padding (a distance) between column #6 and right edge of the TreeWidget. 
As it acts by default the last column with its header keeps resizing to infinity. Instead I would like the last column and its header to maintain its fixed size and column 6 would resize instead. It does look pretty ugly with the last column header ending abruptly at the right edge of the QTreewidget. If keeping the last header/column at fixed size is not an option I would like to know if there are any other ways to achieve the same: to keep last column with its header padded from the right edge of the Tree List widget.

Here is a default look:

[image]

And here is Photoshoped version of what I am looking for:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__() 
        names=['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']
        self.setColumnCount(len(names))
        self.setHeaderLabels(names)
        item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(names)
        self.addTopLevelItem(item)
        self.setColumnWidth(7, 32)
        self.resize(720,120)
        self.show()
tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have solution. First, disable stretch last Section and select resize column.

```
myQTreeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
.
.
.
myQHeaderView = myQTreeWidget.header()
myQHeaderView.setStretchLastSection(False)
myQHeaderView.setResizeMode(6, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

---

**QHeaderView.setResizeMode method Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode

**QHeaderView.setResizeMode enum Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum

---

Implement your code;

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__() 
        names=['Zero','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']
        self.setColumnCount(len(names))
        self.setHeaderLabels(names)
        item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(names)
        self.addTopLevelItem(item)
        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setResizeMode(6, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.resize(720,120)
        self.show()
tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Regards,